# VS2013 Preview high cpu usage when in theory idle

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a asp.net-mvc5 application which I am developing and from time to time I can see in windows server2008r2 task manager that devenv.exe (the visual studio 2013 instance I am using)
is consuming 50%ish cpu usage. Considering this is a quad-core machine that means it must be maxing out two processors. VS still appears to be responsive when this occurs. Is there anything I can run diagnostically to see what feature is causing it?

incidentally I do quite often get errors with the JavaScript language service and it tells me to restart visual studio but this isn't occurring in this scenario.

Comment: Have you already send this feedback to Microsoft? They will help you pinpoint the area so they can fix it before release

Comment: The immediate solution is to clase Taskmanager.

Comment: I have reported same issue last week https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/798561/vwd-2013-express-preview-hang-nuget-package-restored-from-xyz-and-suddenly-its-hang-cpu-usage-is-still-3-but-vwd-perform-as-hang

Comment: I was struggling with a very slow VS2013RC2 for the past few days. Had recently included a lot of JS libraries which VS was trying to index for intellisense. setting <autosync enabled="false" /> at the top of /Scripts/_references.js file brought down the 40% of CPU usage that VS was sitting with even at idle.. read more here http://madskristensen.net/post/the-story-behind-_referencesjs

Answer (score 6):

Try disabling Browser Link:

```
<add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="false" />
```

in your web.config appSettings

Comment: Browserlink is disabled

Comment: +1 I didn't disable it but after reading your post, despite not running the application, I check the browser link dashboard and saw a link there. I closed my browser and CPU went back to idle... Thanks a lot! I will keep this one in mind now.

Comment: Man you save my power. B-)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you start a **[Windows Performance Analyzer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj679884.aspx)** session for CPU Analysis, before starting VS and keep it running in order to capture the issue.

You would be able to see the spike in CPU Usage and link it to the process causing the high usage. You can go even further and find out the module causing "*burning the CPU*".

Comment: How can you drill into see the offending module?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the CPU usage went down when I closed all editor windows (I had number of cshtml and css files open). Somebody else had noticed a similar case when complex CSS files was open [1].

[1] https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/816591/visual-studio-2013-high-cpu-usage-when-idle